# How to use multipole expansion for discrete charge distribution?

Tags: electromagnetism

In page-153, Introductions to Electrodynamics by Griffiths, the following expression is given for the multipole expansion(eqtn-96):

$$ V(r) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^{n+1} } \int (r')^n P_n( \cos \alpha) \rho(r') d \tau' \tag{1}$$

From my understanding, the above formula works only for continuous charge distributions. However on page-155 the high school definition of potential due to two opposite charges seperated at some distance 'd' is said to be deduced from the above (eqtn 99.):

$$ V_{dip} (r) = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \frac{ \vec{p} \cdot \hat{r} }{r^2} \tag{2}$$

I don't understand how (1) can reduce into (2) since this is a discrete distribution. The volume integral seems a bit illdefined here.

After some thought, I guess this perhaps equivalent expression which  should work for discrete charge distributions:

$$ V(r) = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_o} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i} \frac{1}{r^{n+1} } (r')^n P_n ( \cos \alpha) q_i(r') \tag{3}$$

The inner sum is over all the discrete charges. This leads to my question: Is (3) correct and can it be deduced from (1)?

Comment: Just make $\rho$ a delta function.

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, the delta function, at least the one presented in griffiths, is one at only one point.

Comment: Yes but you can have a point charge $q_1$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $q_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$ and then you'd have a charge density of $\rho = q_1 \delta(\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_1) + q_2 \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_2)$, i.e. you can add them together.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't think of that. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it @Wihtedeka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single point charge can be represented by a delta function in the charge distribution and the volume integral will collapse. If you have multiple charges you can sum over different delta functions, for example if you have charge $q_1$ at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and charge $q_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$ your density would be
$$\rho(\mathbf{r}) = q_1 \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_1) + q_2 \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_2) $$
and the volume integral would then only leave $q_1$ exactly at $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $q_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$.